# Can’t concatenate videos with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I’m trying to concatenate a video generated with this command:

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i screenshot.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x1080,subtitles=subs.srt" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -shortest -t 5 -r 30 screenshot.mp4
```

(a 5s video made from a still screenshot with a subtitle on it)

with a video downloaded from Youtube (mp4, h264).

I made sure both videos have the same codecs and the same resolution, but I’ve tried every concatenate command I could find on the web such as these ones and none works :

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i input.txt -c copy output.mp4

ffmpeg -i "concat:screenshot.mp4|input2.mp4" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mp4
```

Specifically, it looks like the second video (the one from Youtube) is slowed down.
Any idea why?

Comment: Do both videos have the same resolution? Otherwise you will have to pad. Also if they have different framerates you 'll have to set a framerate with -r...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this, you have put an -r in front of both so they have the same framerate:

ffmpeg -r 30 -i screenshot.mp4 -r 30 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat[vid]" -map [vid] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "output.mp4"

Comment: looks like it’s working (even though my files had the same framerate, it looks like I still need to specify it here). Can’t believe I haven’t found this mentioned anywhere.